# update AWS ALB routing rules using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement like i have to add/remove routing rules of loadbalancer using cloudformation

I've set up an AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB), along with security groups, target groups, and two EC2 instances manually. Now, I want to use AWS CloudFormation to attach these instances to the target groups and configure routing rules on the ALB. Can someone provide guidance or a CloudFormation template example for this scenario?

And also is it possible to add vm into target groups using cloudformation only?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to update *manually* created resources through CloudFormation. While this is possible for some resources, I highly recommend to migrate or [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) everything to CloudFormation instead of managing a part of your infrastructure. Or if you can, recreate everything via CloudFormation.

---

Anyway, here's how you can manage the `Listener` of your LoadBalancer. Note that this might cause an error if you already have HTTP Listener in your ALB.

```
{
  "Resource": {
    "MyHttpListener": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
          {
            "TargetGroupArn": "TargetGroupArn",
            "Type": "forward"
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": "LoadBalancerArn",
        "Port": 80,
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to setup [Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html) and [Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule-action.html):

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule",
  "Properties" : {
      "Actions" : [ Action, ... ],
      "Conditions" : [ RuleCondition, ... ],
      "ListenerArn" : String,
      "Priority" : Integer
    }
}
```

This is possible because you can just use the ARN of your existing resource.

---

> And also is it possible to add vm into target groups using CloudFormation only?

Yes but you need to import your existing TargetGroup to add the instances via CloudFormation. Since in the [TargetGroup's target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targetdescription.html) you need to specify the instance ID. And it'll be easier to recreate the TargetGroup via CloudFormation.